# libopenjpeg encoding with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, archiving, jpeg2000

The libopenjpeg codec for ffmpeg is deemed experimental. Does anyone know if it is useable for storage of archival video material, i.e. if I write a whole bunch of video files with it, am I likely top be able to open them in the future?

Is there any other Free/OSS alternative to using ffmpeg for encoding motionJpeg2000, or for archiving video in general?

Answer (score 0):

Even though they are experimental, they will still be complaint to the standard. So, you should always be able to open them. The quality of the encoding may not be guaranteed, so you may see artifacts, try their best preset.

Comment: I did some tests and was getting massive colour shifts, as well as severe blockiness. It certainly didn't look lossless.

Comment: JPEG is not a lossless format. But the loss if encoded at high percentage of quality should not be visible to the human eye.